# Convince Sony Cyber-shot DSC-H300 to take many pictures after one shutter press?

Tags: sony, burst-mode

A friend of mine does cosplay and wants to be able to take pictures of her costumes.  She's got a backdrop set up in her house, and is currently just using her smartphone but is not happy with the image quality.  She had picked up a DSC-H300 (not HX300) but now we're thinking this through a little more.

What she would like to be able to do, is to activate the camera (whether by hitting the shutter release on the camera itself, or some kind of remote), get into position, and then have the camera take multiple shots (at least 5) a few seconds apart, giving her time to move to a different pose for each shot.  Holding some kind of remote (especially a wired remote) is not an option as it would be visible in the shot.

I've seen the phrase "burst mode" bandied about, but it seems like that almost always applies to images taken as quickly as possible, and almost always while the shutter is being manually held down.

We had been looking into various remotes (like [this one](https://smile.amazon.com/SUPON-Replacement-RM-VPR1-Shutter-Compatible/dp/B012APPEJE/ref=sr_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=sony%20camera%20time%20lapse%20control&qid=1609177406&sr=8-7)) but we are starting to get the feeling that the H300 doesn't support remote control.  There's an [app on the Sony page](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/www/disoft/int/playmemories-mobile/en/operation/dsc_remote_and.html) that mentions "Smart Remote Control" but again, it's feeling like the H300 doesn't support it.

The H300 does something called "continuous shooting" which might do the trick, it's hard to tell from the description in the user manual:

[image]

But maybe some combination of self-timer and continuous shooting will record 5 images at 0.8 images per second?

EDIT

There is a comment on Amazon, supposed from Sony themselves, saying that the VPR1 doesn't work with the DSC-H300:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use the timer with continuous shooting enabled?

Comment: That works!  After pressing the shutter it waits 10 seconds and then takes 10 pictures, one per second (or so).  She's going to get the remote (since it's returnable) and see if that will work as well.  One unfortunate limitation is that it doesn't re-focus between each shot, but that's not a big deal for her.

Answer (score 1):

The manual page you refer to in your question indicates that when continuous shooting is enabled and...

> ... recording with the self-timer, a series of up to 5 images is recorded.

So using the timer with continuous shooting enabled [should do what your friend desires](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/121889/convince-sony-cyber-shot-dsc-h300-to-take-many-pictures-after-one-shutter-press/121890#comment234620_121889).